# Why the following code prints 1 as output?

Tags: c, pointers

difference of pointer gives 1 as output..

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    int a=5,b=10;
    int *p=&a,*q=&b;
    int c=p-q;
    printf("%d",c); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because they happen to lie one `int` apart in memory, and pointer arithmetic counts in terms the underlying type rather than bytes.

Comment: but is it always that pointers would lie one int apart in memory..?

Comment: No, this is unspecified, you cannot rely on the fact but often you will find it to be true because the compiler allocates local variables on the stack in the order he finds them in code. Things are very different if you have int and float variables however.

Comment: @RajeshSethi: Note that it's `a` and `b` that happen to lie one `int` apart in memory (this is not guaranteed -- see DrKoch's comment), not `p` and `q`. `p-q` is just subtracting two pointers (addresses) that happen to be stored in `p` and `q`. At the machine code level, subtracting two pointers will give a difference in bytes (likely, on practical machines), but the semantics of C transform that into a count of `int`s (or whatever the pointed-to type is), by implicitly dividing by `sizeof(int)` if you will.

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting two pointers which are not pointing to same array make no sense.

#### C11: 6.5.6 Additive operators (p8)

> [...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the **same array object**, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the **behavior is undefined**.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that non-array objects are considered arrays of length 1 the purposes of this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting pointers here:

```
int c=p-q;
```

You ought to do this:

```
int c=*p-*q;
```

Its a matter of chance that the location of the 2 pointers are near otherwise you could get any value. Thanks to [haccks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520756/why-the-following-code-prints-1-as-output/29520783#29520783) - please read this:

#### C11: 6.5.6 Additive operators (p8)

> [...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the **behavior is undefined**.

Comment: seems I missed smth:"and the result point to elements of the same array "-how can result of subtraction point to some element?

Comment: @Giorgi - if you would substract 2 pointers within the same array then you may reach an element in the same array. Eg. `arr[10]` - `8 - 2  = 6` - note 6 is valid index here.

Comment: @Giorgi; Read the complete para quoted from the standard and you will understand the whole story.

Comment: @haccks:yeah thought so-just didn't have that doc nearby

Answer (score 1):

to let `p-q` make sense,p and q should point to the same array.
but `p-q` in your code is Undefined

Answer (score 1):

The way C is usually implemented is that a function allocates some space on the *stack*, and all local variables that need to have memory addresses are placed in this space.

It seems natural that the variables would be placed in this memory in some natural ordering, such as the order they are declared or its reverse, or maybe alphabetically.

Furthermore, `int` variables usually pack well into memory.

Thus, it's natural to expect that `a` and `b` are stored in adjacent memory locations, and that `&a - &b` would either be `1` or `-1`.

Now, you shouldn't rely on anything reasonable happening here; the C standard doesn't guarantee anything about what result you should get, or even imply that it's meaningful to ask for the difference in the first place. This is *undefined behavior*, because `a` and `b` are completely independent objects. The C standard permits this difference to return `1`, `-1`, `42`, and even allows your program to wipe your hard drive, ruin your credit score, or even return a result so unfathomable to the human mind it's only by analogy we call it a number at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here, **c** holds difference of two integer type address. And this difference is 1. 5 is stored in an address and 10 is also stored in an address. **p** and **q** are those address who stores this 5 and 10.